# Parallel Port Interfacing in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, parallel-processing, port, interfacing

Hi I am having problem in interfacing Parallel port using Assembly Language and TASM for assembly.

Here is the sample source code:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
.code

main:           
    mov dx, 378h
    mov al, 00001000b 
    out dx, al ; output

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

end main
```

The problem is the out command doesn't work or change the status of the parallel port. I have an LED circuit to test the output of the parallel port and it's not working. I have tried other program available in the net to check the status of the parallel port and I confirmed that the status of the port is not changing.

Do I have to do something to make this work like enabling debug mode in kernel or something like that? Thank you!

Comment: What are you running this under?

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply Ross. I'm running this under Windows 7 32-bit and my processor is AMD.

Comment: The Windows MS-DOS emulator may not support what you're trying to do here. It doesn't give you direct access to the hardware. Instead your OUT instruction will be handled by a virtual parallel port driver. It's only designed to handle normal printing operations, and probably has to access the real parallel port through standard Windows APIs.

Comment: @RossRidge, thank you for the fast reply.

Is there any way to make my MS-DOS emulator get an access to my hardware? I was able to used this before in a different PC years ago without any problem but I can't use it now on my current PC.

Comment: With such current computer which no more LPT or serial port, how do we know the address we can assign to output to a device?

Answer (score 0):

Win-7 (32bit) needs UP Driver for it to access parallel port.
Windows XP does not need it.

[UPDriver for Win7-32Bit](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?redir_token=C_qbcG9FVYysVdIo7yvLHbmeE_d8MTUyOTk1NTE1MUAxNTI5ODY4NzUx&q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediafire.com%2Fdownload%2Fptj394ezwv7crnb&v=8rNrhCmC7w4&event=video_description)

Source is [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rNrhCmC7w4). 
Its a bit late, but sure will help someone.
Have tested it.